# How to call a get REST API from a tvOS Application using Xamarin?

Tags: tvos, rest

I am trying to call a get REST API from my tvOS application. Following is my code when tap the Button:

```
async void ButtonClicked(UIButton sender)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var response = await client.GetAsync("rest api url");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Response.ToString()))
                    {
                        var category = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Videos>(Response.ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine("count:>>" + category.webContentCategoryList.Count);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>"+e);
            }
```

I have installed the `system.net.http` and `newtonsoft.json` nuget packages. But when I run the project the application showing `Main.cs` file like below screenshot:

[image]

Am I missing something in this?

**UPDATE**

I have added breakpoint for the first line inside `ButtonClicked` function. When I taps the Button, the application showing `Main.cs` file like above screenshot. It is not hitting the first line of `ButtonClicked` function.

So the issue is something else, I am not an expert in tvOS applications so I can't figure out. I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H5l4J_RPqnbyBYDetVVjjn_LbhTnxbtt/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by separating the service call on a new function like below, new function is the async method:

```
partial void ButtonClicked(UIButton sender)
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    async void LoadData()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("service url");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Response.ToString()))
            {
                var category = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Videos>(Response.ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine("count:>>" + category.Count);
            }
        }
    }
```

My XF [Thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/414874#Comment_414874) is here for more details.